# node.jsのconnectモジュールでミドルウェアの順番を動的に変えることは可能か？

Tags: javascript, node.js

connectモジュールを使って、順次処理をしていくとします。

```
var connect = require('connect');

connect()
    .use(funcA)
    .use(funcB)
    .use(funcC);
    .listen(3000);
```

ここで、funcAの処理の内容によって、funcBを経由せずにfuncCに行くことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 知りたいことは「どうすればいいか」ではなくて可否ですか？(もし方法を知りたいのであれば具体的なコードを示し、質問の修正を。)

Comment: この文脈で質問しているので、方法を聞いていると考えるのが普通かと思います。また、質問の内容的にconnectの基本的な使い方を知っていれば、サンプルコードとしてはこれで十分だと判断しました。

Comment: 初期のころと比べて、質問文の厳密さを無理に求めすぎるコメントが多くなったように思います。
みなさんそこにこだわり過ぎでは？
あきらかに聞きたい事の意図が分かるのに質問文の修正を求められたり。
もちろん本当に稚拙な質問も多くなったので仕方ない部分もありますが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡潔に言えば、それはできません。それぞれの函数の呼び出しは独立からです。

独立とは、

```
var connect = require('connect');

connect().use(funcA).use(funcB).use(funcC).listen(3000);
```

と

```
var connect = require('connect');

var tmp1 = connect();
var tmp2 = tmp1.use(funcA)
var tmp3 = tmp2.use(funcB)
var tmp4 = tmp3.use(funcC)
tmp4.listen(3000);
```

とが等価であること。

---

ですが、ECMAScript6に導入されたPromiseオブジェクトを使えばできるかも知れませんが、いい方法とは思えません。

funcAとfuncBとfuncCの処理を一つの関数にまとめてはどう思いますか。それなら、処理の流れはよく管理できるようになるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり順番の制御は無理なのですね。